# Prepare name and address for use with drupal_mail()

Tags: 7, emails

I'm having problems with certain characters when using the `drupal_mail()` function.

Here is the apache error.log entry for the issue:

> Ignoring invalid 'To:' recipient address '=?UTF-8?B?IsWgxZLFvcWhxZPFvsW4wqXCtcOAw4HDgsODw4TDhcOGw4fDiMOJw4rDi8OMw40=?=  =?UTF-8?B?w47Dj8OQw5HDksOTw5TDlcOWw5jDmcOaw5vDnMOdw5/DoMOhw6LDo8Okw6XDpg==?=  =?UTF-8?B?w6fDqMOpw6rDq8Osw63DrsOvw7DDscOyw7PDtMO1w7bDuMO5w7rDu8O8w73DvyI=?=  =?UTF-8?B?IDxjaXRyaWNndXlAZ21haWwuY29tPg==?='
>   Transaction aborted: no recipients specified

For sake of example, what would be the simplest way to successfully send an email (In the [RFC2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) format of "`User <user@example.com>`") to:

```
ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñóôõöøùúûýÿ <example@example.com>
```

Currently drupal_mail() fails with:

> "Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem
>   persists."

Preferably, I would like to be able to keep these special characters intact.

Otherwise, could I use a project like Transliteration or Pathauto to convert or prepare the string? If so, which project and function should I use to prepare the "To" name?

Drupal Log Message:
[image]

Comment: The watchdog log (dblog.module) should contain more information, including the actual error message.

Comment: Attached a graphic of the error from watchdog. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credit to @deceze

[Original Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669668/how-to-use-special-characters-in-recipients-name-when-using-phps-mail-function/7670192#7670192)

In short:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

$name  = '山本';
$email = 'yamamoto@example.com';
$addr  = mb_encode_mimeheader($name, 'UTF-8', 'Q') . " <$email>";
```